# Transparent background color, but not transparent text in IE 6 and 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I tried to follow the advices in [CSS: semi-transparent background, but not text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text).  I'm happy of the results in Firefox, Safari, Opera and Chrome. With these browsers I obtain a result similar to the one below, where you can see the background in transparency under the header. However, I've problems with IE.

You should [click here to see the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhrAJ/).

[image: Expected Result]

In IE8 is OK, but in IE6/7 there is no colored band at all. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: check out a similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975688/css-background-opacity-with-rgba-not-working-in-ie-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `div.header`:

**Remove:**

```
background-color: #0a5787;
background: transparent;
```

**Add:**

```
background: none;
zoom: 1;
```

**Change:**

```
/* For IE 5.5-7 */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#900a5787, endColorstr=#900a5787);
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#900a5787, endColorstr=#900a5787)";
```

This works on IE7 when I test it and in theory I'm sure it should work in IE6, but on my emulator it is not working.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3jEbC/**

Comment: In the meantime I tried the PNG trick http://jsfiddle.net/xhrAJ/10/ which works with IE7 and gives a full color in IE6. However your solution is PERFECT! It also works with IE6, you're awesome! Thank you!

Comment: ah finally I understand that MS string like #900a5787, the first two hex digits are the transparency and the other 6 the color!

Comment: @stivlo I believe the browser makes a call to the DirectX API which is why it is backwards. Check out this blog post: [How to use RGBA() in IE](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/)