# Transparent Background in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I set a transparent background in a `div` element. It's child element don't have a transparent background.

I have:

```
background: rgba(181, 182, 183, 0.6);
```

For IE, i tried below:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B5B6B700, endColorstr=#B5B6B700);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B5B6B700, endColorstr=#B5B6B700)";
```

What would be the correct `hex` value? Im not sure on the last two digits.

Answer (score 0):

Try @MatTheCat's answer here for an IE transparent background fallback: [CSS background opacity with rgba not working in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975688/css-background-opacity-with-rgba-not-working-in-ie-8)

Looking at your current code, if you are having trouble getting the background to be transparent, you may need to add `zoom: 1` in order to trigger hasLayout in IE.

Try this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B5B6B700,endColorstr=#B5B6B7000); 
zoom: 1;
```

[More info](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout) on hasLayout.