# Transparency in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, transparent

I am testing a new site. [CLICK HERE](http://ceskakoruna.com/)
Problem is that in IE the Header, Footer, and  LEFT RIGHT Arrows on homepage are not transparent. But in Firefox and Chrome yes.

Any ideas how to fix this and make them transparent in IE?
Thanks

Comment: I guess this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975688/css-background-opacity-with-rgba-not-working-in-ie-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opactiy doesn't work in IE. You have to use PNG images ! In your case, you'll have to use two different images : normal, and hover.