# Iframe transparent background on Fancybox 2.1.4

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, background, transparent, fancybox-2

As per title, adding the below to remove background on Fancybox 2.1.4 works fine on Safari, FF & Chrome but not IEs. (only tested on IE8)

```
beforeShow: function(){
    //transparent background
    $(".fancybox-skin").css("background","transparent");

    //remove dropshadow
    $(".fancybox-skin").css("-webkit-box-shadow","0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
    $(".fancybox-skin").css("-moz-box-shadow","0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
    $(".fancybox-skin").css("box-shadow","0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
}
```

Comment: rgba colors are not supported in IE8. For solution please read [CSS background opacity with rgba not working in IE 8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3975688/1693859)

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you having issues with? Features like `rgba` and `box-shadow` aren't supported natively in older versions.

Comment: The rbga is to remove the drop shadow, not the background color.

Comment: Solution found after trying diff. settings, stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post the answer in 6 hours, will post details after that. Problem lies at the iframe attribute: must be set to allowtransparency="true".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around the Fancybox's src files, the problem is at the iframe "allowtransparency" attribute.

In jquery.fancybox.js line 140, replace the line with below:

```
iframe   : '<iframe id="fancybox-frame{rnd}" name="fancybox-frame{rnd}" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen allowtransparency="true"></iframe>',
```