# Fancybox v2 – remove white background?

Tags: css, fancybox, transparency, lightbox, fancybox-2

I will try my best to explain this -->

I am using Fancybox and everything works great. Here comes the issue.

I want to remove the white background as well as the shadow of the iframe-pop, not the overlay! 
I tried playing around with the css files which didn't really work...

If you click on the "#1" square you can see what I mean : http://testingpage.de/ 
(I destroyed the background image on purpose to see the white bg.)

Thanks for any and all help and advice!

**UPDATE:**

Because of the helpful tips I could get rid of the white background of images. It's still not working for iframe...

Comment: remove these two rules from line 41 of fancybox css: `-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);-moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);` and the box shadow should be removed

Comment: problem 1/2 solved, thanks! Now I just have to get rid of the white bg...

Comment: What happens when you trigger something that isn't an iframe in a fancybox?

Comment: The transparency is working if i trigger a regular image. The problem seems to be iframe...

Comment: have you tried removing the background colour in the fancybox options? try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482779/iframe-transparent-background-on-fancybox-2-1-4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to edit the original css file ... just add this in your custom css file and after loading the fancybox css file

```
.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0;
}
```

then your script

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    padding: 0 // remove white border
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Cb65Z/)**

**EDIT** :

For a full transparent background, also add

```
.fancybox-skin {background: transparent}
```

in your custom css file

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Cb65Z/1/)**

**NOTE**: this make fancybox transparent BUT the background of your `iframe` content (`body`, `html`) should be transparent too

Comment: Thanks, but I don't just want to remove the border. I want to remove the white background behind the image. I attached a screenshot for clarification. The white area should be transparent instead of white: http://i.imgur.com/gPu9daM.png

Comment: Thanks! It's transparent for images, the iframe bg is still white.

Comment: @Costa you need to edit (individually) the css of the pages opened inside the iframe because so far they have css background `#fff` property