# How can I change the different opacity rate of an element inside of another

Tags: css

I have a button that changes opacity with `:hover`, but inside there's an image that shouldn't be affected by the button's opacity change.

For example, something like this:

```
.expandIMG:hover{
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.expandIMG:hover,div,img{
  opacity: 1; // this make no opacity but for all the button an i just want    
              // the image that are inside of some div.
}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, a child element cannot have an opacity higher than the parent.

Comment: @Devin , i think your right, The parent's opacity controls all children

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to change the opacity of the div containing the image to 0.6 while keeping the image's opacity at 1.

You can accomplish this using `background: rgba(0,0,0,1)` instead of opacity:

```
.expandIMG {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.expandIMG:hover{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

This way, you're only changing the alpha (opacity) of the div's background while the images inside it aren't affected.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2krc5080/

Answer (score -3):

You could also try to set the z-index of the image higher while hovering. And maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16943891/4533109) is also useful to you.

```
.expandIMG:hover img {

  z-index: 9999; // more than the expandIMG 

}
```

Come on please give me more downvotes!! Feed me!!

Comment: Number 1: z-index does not work on static positioned elements!