# rgba() not working properly in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I want to design a box with some transparency in it in CSS or CSS3 which must work in IE8, I made this code, it is working fine in other browsers, but in IE8 the box is becoming completely transparent, how to fix this problem?

> ```
> .price_tag {
>     position: absolute;
>     height: 146px;
>     width: 295px;
>     left: 210px;
>     top: 241px;
>     background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.7);
>     border-radius: 8px;
>     z-index: 200;
>
>     -webkit-box-shadow: -2px -2px 6px rgba(255,255,255, 1) inset, 2px 0px 4px rgba(255,255,255,1) inset;
>
>     box-shadow: -2px -2px 6px rgba(255,255,255, 1) inset, 2px 0px 4px rgba(255,255,255,1) inset;
>
>     behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc); 
> }
> ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS background opacity with rgba not working in IE 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975688/css-background-opacity-with-rgba-not-working-in-ie-8)

Comment: `rgba()` is not supported in IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rgba` is not supported in IE8, for fallback tricks, this might be helpful 
http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 1):

You have to "hack" the opacity effect in IE8.

One way to do this is by using a 1x1 transparent png with:

```
background-image: url(<path to your url>);
```

Another way is by using ms-filters:

```
opacity : 0.7;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
```

But with last one there is an inconvenient. All the selector will be "alphaed" to 0.7. So you shall put your content (text, images, whatever...) in another container.