# Opacity declaration is inherited from parent even if declared explicitly

Tags: html, css

I have following CSS

```
.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown-menu > li {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}
```

When HTML element (which uses this above CSS) is loaded I'm getting opacity sets as expected from `.dropdown-menu`, the problem is that this opacity is inherited inside `dropdown-menu > li` element event when I'm using an `!important` declaration on opacity.

So how to overcome this (Opacity should remain 0.6 on parent element) and on this child I want opacity 1?

Comment: Afaik this is not possible. If a parent element has opacity, all child elements have at most that opacity. If both the parent and child have .5 opacity, the child has effectively .25 opacity.

Comment: @Paulie_D Wrong question tagged as a duplicate and should be reopened or re voted to another question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `opacity` for the parent element, declare your colors in `rgba` format.

```
.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);   
}
```

This way, you will retain the `opacity` of the parent element, as well as your child elements will have an opacity of 1.

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors) for the same is pretty decent as well.

---

Also, I read this in your question, *"The problem is that this opacity is inherited"*

No, it isn't inherited.

Comment: this is the correct answer, especially with the addendum about the inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to know that [opacity](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/opacity) sets the opacity value for an element and all of its children; where [RGBA](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Color/RGBA) sets the opacity value only for a single declaration.

So you should use something like:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);   
}
```

(*Of course, you can also use the [HSLA](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Color/HSLA)-property for this.*)

Remember that the `opacity`-property isn't fully supported by all browsers, please check this SA-topic for more info on this: [CSS background opacity with rgba not working in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975688/css-background-opacity-with-rgba-not-working-in-ie-8)